# jquery numberOfInvalids( ) function is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin 1.9.0 . I have downloaded the plugin from here:  http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

I have copied the following code from this link http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/numberOfInvalids 
to find out the number of errors I have in my form. But it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.delete').click(function() {
        invalidHandler: function() {
            $("#summary").text(validator.numberOfInvalids() + " field(s) are invalid");
        }
    });
});
```

And then

```
<div id="summary" class="summary"> </div>
<a href="#" class="delete">click</a>
```

My form head looks like this:

```
<form class="uniform"  autocomplete="off" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?echo base_url();?>addteacher_salary/add " method="post" name="myForm">
```

I don't call any validation function in my form, I just load the validation plugin inside head tag and the validation works.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with the code?

## Edit

My Complete form looks like following:

```
   <form class="uniform"  autocomplete="off" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?echobase_url();?>addteacher_salary/add " method="post" name="myForm">      

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Select A Teacher</legend>
                    <dl class="inline">


                        <dt><label for="teachername">Teacher Name <span class="hello">*</span></label></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <?php echo form_dropdown('teacherid', $dropdown_teacher,'', 'class="medium required" id="teacherid"' ); ?>



                        </dd>

                        <dt><label for="salary_month">Month of Salary <span class="hello">*</span></label></dt>
                        <dd>
                        <?php   $month_options = array(     
                                                         ''  => 'Select',   
                                                         'January'  => 'January',
                                                         'February'    => 'February',
                                                         'March'   => 'March',
                                                         'April'    => 'April',
                                                         'May'   => 'May',
                                                         'June'  => 'June',
                                                         'July'    => 'July',
                                                         'August'   => 'August',
                                                         'September'    => 'September',
                                                         'October'   => 'October',
                                                         'November'   => 'November',
                                                         'December' => 'December',
                                                        );


                                        echo form_dropdown('salary_month', $month_options,'', 'class="medium required"'  );?>

                        </dd>

                        <dt><label for="salary_year"> Year of Salary <span class="hello">*</span></label></dt>
                        <dd>



                        <?php 
                            $year_options = array(      
                                                         ''  => 'Select',   
                                                         '2010'  => '2010',
                                                        '2011'  => '2011',
                                                        '2012'  => '2012',
                                                        '2013'  => '2013',
                                                        '2014'  => '2014',

                                                         '2015'    => '2015',
                                                         '2016'   => '2016',
                                                         '2017'    => '2017',
                                                         '2018'   => '2018',
                                                         '2019'  => '2019',
                                                         '2020'    => '2020',
                                                         '2021'   => '2021',
                                                         '2022'    => '2022',
                                                         '2023'   => '2023',
                                                         '2024'   => '2024',
                                                         '2025' => '2025',
                                                        '2026' => '2026',
                                                        '2027' => '2027',
                                                        '2028' => '2028',
                                                        '2029' => '2029',
                                                        '2030' => '2030',
                                                        );


                                        echo form_dropdown('salary_year', $year_options,'', 'class="medium required"'  );?>

                        </dd>

                        <dt><label for="salary_disbursement_date">Salary Disbursement Date <span class="hello">*</span></label></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <input type="text" name="salary_disbursement_date" id="datepicker2" maxlength="10" class="medium required" />

                        </dd>



                        <dt><label for="salaryamount">Salary Amount <span class="hello">*</span></label></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <input type="text" name="salary_amount" id="salary_amount" value="" class="medium required number" />

                        </dd>




                    </dl>

                <div class="buttons">
                        <button id="submit_item" name="submit_item" type="submit" class="button">Submit Button</button>

                    </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: What do your form fields look like?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker thanks for your reply. Please check the edited part of my post above. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to call `valid` on the form *before* calling `numberOfInvalids`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.delete').click(function() {
        $("#myForm").valid(); // Make validate calculate the number of invalid fields.
        var numInvalid = $("#myForm").numberOfInvalids();

        $("#summary").text(numInvalid + " field(s) are invalid");
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UURz2/

Comment: Thanks man.. Although I had to make some changes in script(also had to cut the link to validation plugin from line 32 to just before the end of head tag ).. it is working perfectly now.. thanks a lot man.. you helped me a lot. :)